# OpenCL: Device / Host memory coherence for variables passed to kernel with CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR

Tags: opencl

If a variable is passed to kernel with CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, does it mean any change to the variable in the device would be also shown in host memory?

I am in a scenario where I am using CPU as the device instead of GPU, so everything passed to kernel will be marked with CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR.

If this is true, then I no longer need to read everything back to host, which is very convenient.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your understanding is correct, except one possible pitfall: [documentation](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateBuffer.html) states that

> OpenCL implementations are allowed to cache the buffer contents
>   pointed to by `host_ptr` in device memory. This cached copy can be used
>   when kernels are executed on a device.

This means that changes to data performed by kernel might not be immediately reflected in `host_ptr`. In fact, there is no guarantee that `host_ptr` contains valid data while it is used for buffer.

In order to have valid and up-to-date data you must force synchronization. The offcial documentation is a little vague about this moment, but [buffer mapping/unmapping](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.1/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueMapBuffer.html) definetly works:

> If the buffer object is created with `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` set in
>   `mem_flags`, the `host_ptr` specified in `clCreateBuffer` is guaranteed to
>   contain the latest bits in the region being mapped when the
>   `clEnqueueMapBuffer` command has completed; and the pointer value
>   returned by `clEnqueueMapBuffer` will be derived from the `host_ptr`
>   specified when the buffer object is created.

Here is an example adapted from [Khronos group forum post](https://www.khronos.org/message_boards/viewtopic.php?p=14184#p14184):

```
cl_mem device_output = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE | CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR, size, original_output, NULL);
// run the kernel
void* pointer = clEnqueueMapBuffer(queue, device_output, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, size, 0, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL);
// work with 'original_output'
clEnqueueUnmapMemObject(queue, device_output, pointer, 0, NULL, NULL);
clReleaseMemObject(device_output);
```

Comment: This is a subtle gotcha and I've been bitten by this too, so it's good you brought this up.

Comment: @aland i think i am asking very late.. But instead of mapping the memory, if i am waiting using event.. will it update my proper array in host device? for me it is working (might be i am using event for let the kernel finish). but then can i skip the mapping?

Comment: @Vishwadeep Just waiting for kernel to finish executing is [*not* enough](http://www.khronos.org/message_boards/showthread.php/6912-Clarify-CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR?p=22099&viewfull=1#post22099). Your approach might work, especitally if fine you only use CPU as compute device, but that's still undefined behavior.

Comment: yes @aland you found correctly i am using CPU as computing device. thanks for your answer.